# Hibernate @Email validation allows email with quote in domain part

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, email

I am using hibernate-validator 4.1.0 and its email validator `@Email` allows emails containing quote symbol in domain part. 
For example, test@my.com' is valid according to hibernate `@Email` validation.
In email specification such symbol is not allowed in domain part. Therefore, I have concerns that mail server can not send email which is valid according to hibernate validation.
Is it possible to configure hibernate validation to reject such emails?

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid.

If it was `t'est@my.com` then it will be valid, email is divided into a local and domain part. The domain part can't contain `'`

You can read [RFC 952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952) and [1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) concerning the domain part of the email.

You're just doing syntax validation, but you can also take a bit further, where you can test to see if the domain actually exists. Then if it exists you can to do a SMTP Transaction to see if the email is really valid.

A good [Email Hygiene Tool](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/services/bulkemail/) will do validations from basic syntax checking all the way to SMTP Validations.

Comment: Sure specified in question email is not valid. But hibernate bean validation does not think so. It allows such emails like valid. So validation passes and error happens during sending email on mail server.